# space between lines is not correct

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

The space between two lines in a paragraph should be 1.5 lines which is according to my university requirements it equivalents to 0.21 inch. In LaTeX, I used the package setspace as follows:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
```

However, when I measure the space between the lines I find out that the distance is 0.22 inch, while the requirements of my university is 0.21 inch. I have searched in this valued site and even in Google but I did not find answer. Would somebody help me please to adjust the distance?

Comment: I see some university official is trying to justify his existence at your expense.  My condolences.

Comment: What size option do you use? The default `10pt` or `11pt` or `12pt`?

Comment: A minimal example is needed, because I can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the recommended way of doing things, but you can put

```
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10}{0.21in}\selectfont}
```

in your document preamble. This won't affect `\section` headings or any text in a different size. If your text size is not 10 pt, replace the `10` in the `\fontsize` command with your desired size.

That said, I don't think anyone's going to notice a difference of 0.01 inches.

Comment: The difference *is* noticeable: it's a quarter of a millimeter, so 30 lines make a difference of about 7mm (one third of an inch).

Comment: Thank you @ChrisS, your Answer was good but it gives distance of 0.24 inch. Accordingly I reduced the number 0.21in of your answer to 0.19in, now the output is exactly 0.21in in the pdf file. Thank you again.

Comment: @Montadar -- the fact that an explicitly specified dimension doesn't measure what you expect it to be might indicate that the printer you are using is out of adjustment, and if the document were printed on another printer, it might very well display different results.  before printing out your final copy, you should probably test for this possibility.